# Finding Laurent series and classifying singularities

Tags: complex-analysis

Find out the points of singularities of the following function and classify them:

$f(z)=tan(\frac{1}{z}).$

my idea here is the following:

the singular points are $z=\frac{2}{(2n+1)\pi}$ (isolated).

also,z$\to$0 as n$\to$$\infty$

so, 0 is a point of non isolated essential singularity.

now, for the isolated singularities z=$\frac{2}{(2n+1)\pi}$, we can always find the Laurent series and classify the singularities.
but, I am completely stuck in finding the laurent seires of following function:

f(z)=tan($\frac{1}{z}$)  at  say,z=$\frac{2}{3\pi}$

my idea was to put z-$\frac{2}{3\pi}$=t and find out the expansion of tan($\frac{1}{t+\frac{2}{3\pi}}$) at t=0 and then i am completely stuck.is this method coreect ??if not,suggest alternatives.

any help would be appreciated....

Comment: Your method is correct. How does one find Laurent series in general?—taking derivatives, perhaps?

Comment: @gregmartin:can you find the expansion at thegiven point??

Comment: the first step when searching for a Laurent series is to find if the coefficients are non zero when $n \to \infty$ and/or when $n \to -\infty$, and to notice that it is nothing more than a Fourier series

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For classification purpose your method is correct but alternatively one can do the following,

If $P$ is isolated singular point and $\lim_{z \to P}|f(z)|=+\infty $ then $f$ has pole at $P$. Further here in your example look at $g(z)=1/f(z)$ in a nbd around $z=2/3 \pi$ say, then $g$ has simple zero at $z=2/3 \pi$ so $f$ will have simple pole at that point.

Further if you need to find Laurent series expansion, you can use the following formula to find the Laurent series coefficients $a_j$ of $f$ expanded about point $P$, for $j=-k, -k+1, ...$

$a_j=\dfrac{1}{(k+j)!}\bigg(\dfrac{\partial}{\partial z} \bigg)^{k+j} ((z-P)^k.f)\bigg |_{z=P}$ where $k$ is order of pole and

In your example $k=1$.

Comment: :how do we get the $a_j$ you described

Comment: $a_j$ is the coefficient in Laurent series expansion where $j=-k, -k+1, ...$

Comment: :is it true that if |f(z)|$\to$$\infty$ as z$\to$$z_0$ (where $z_0$ is isolated singularity),then,z=$z_0$ is a pole??because i know that this condition is true if we are given that z=$z_0$ is a pole

Comment: :i am trying to find laurent series to show that at the given point we obtain the pole.the formula that you are giving gives the laurent series after knowing the orer of pole

Comment: yes it is true. in some books this is used as a definition of pole.

Comment: can you mention the book please.i need to be sure on this..

Comment: refer https://books.google.com.br/books?id=9LtfZr1snG0C&printsec=frontcover&hl=pt-BR&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false  page 105

Comment: :how in this problem we can use laurent expansion to classify singular points

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34465/discussion-between-abhishek-shrivastava-and-prajakta).